# Present Perfect Progressive in scientific writing?

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, science, present-progressive

Scientific writing is generally supposed to be written in *present tense* (focus on proof of the existence of the result, not how the author arrived at it).

However, I have a case where this results in verbose writing, with the important concepts at the end of the sentences.

Which of the two should I choose?

**1. Present Perfect Progressive**

> Automatic language detection has been performed on the 10045139 labels of the 2015-5-9 snapshot of X. The 983 datasets have been sorted in descending order by the percentage of labels detected as English. The first 50 datasets with at least 100 labels that were confirmed as labeled in English by manual inspection were chosen for the benchmark with two questions for each selected dataset.

**2. Present**

> The 10045139 labels of the 2015-5-9 snapshot of X are each assigned an estimated language tag by automatic language detection. Each of the 983 datasets is assigned a score s = |number of labels detected as English|/|number of labels|. The benchmark comprises the 50 datasets with the highest score s for which (1) manual inspection confirms the language as English (2) the number of labels in total is at least 100. The benchmark contains two questions for each dataset.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that scientific writing is "generally" to be written in the present tense?  Proof is for baking, brewing, minting, and mathematics, not science, which is about the best models that fit the evidence to date..  The essence of science is how the experimenter arrived at the result.  Try getting your verbs out of the passive voice and use the simple past tense.

Comment: *not how the author arrived at it* -- I guess it depends on whether you're a theorist or an experimentalist.  At any rate, you need to describe your procedure clearly so others can try to reproduce your results.